# How to count how many data frames are in a list in R

Tags: r, list, count

I have a list that has some lists inside (data at the end), and at the very end, it has a dataframe. How can I count how many dataframes are in total?

I was trying with:

```
sapply(b, function(x) sum(is.data.frame(x))
```

But it only counted at the first level, what can I do to get to the very last level?

How can I accomplish this?

### Data

---

`dput()` is massive, (even in the smallest example), so I upload it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vRBN21RC3GSrlXMcP5oFYzSHgGBXlfZn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Rather than sharing a massive example, I'd suggest creating a small example that illustrates the problem. It's usually easier to work on a small example and then scale it up than go straight to a massive problem. Do you have other objects in the nested lists, or is it lists with data frames all the way down? Seems like either something like `list(a1 = 1, a2 = mtcars, a3 = list(b1 = mtcars), a4 = list(c1 = mtcars, c2 = list(c21 = mtcars, c22 = "a")))` might be a good example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a well-controlled recursive function should suffice.

```r
func <- function(z) {
  if (inherits(z, "data.frame")) return(TRUE)
  if (is.list(z)) return(sum(sapply(z, func)))
  FALSE
}

L <- list(a=1, b=mtcars, d=list(mtcars,mtcars), e=list(mtcars,list(mtcars)))
func(L)
# [1] 5
```